# HtmlUnit: Extract text from a <span> after an <a> tag

Tags: java, html, xml, dom, htmlunit

I am trying to extract some Data from a webpage via HtmlUnit. This data is firstnames and lastnames of some of my students. The data is organized like this:

```
<td width='20%' align='left' valign='top' class='textstyle1'>
<a href='page.html' name='specName' class='seriousClass'>Secondname</a>, 
<span class='textstyle2'>Firstname</span></td><td width='15%' align='center' 
valign='top' class='textstyle2'>&nbsp;</td>
```

At the moment I can only extract the secondname like this:

```
List studentsFieldList = page2.getElementsByName("specName");
for (int i = 0; i<studentsFieldList.size(); i++){
String lastName     = ((Node)studentsFieldList.get(i)).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}
```

I cannot get the firstname out. I tryed to use

```
String firstName     = ((Node)studentsFieldList.get(i)).getPreviousSibling().getFirstChild.getNodeValue();
```

but it does not work. The String is empty, although the debugger shows me the right value in the studentsFieldList Object.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it myself. The problem is, that you cannot access the methods of your NodeList deeper than the first Daughter-Node although the code completion of your IDE tells you, that you can.

When I want to get the String firstName in the above example, I have to extract the daughter Node from within the NodeList:

```
Node firstNameNode = (Node)studentsFieldList.get(i)).getPreviousSiblin();
String firstname = firstNameNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```